# loading hickle file(comes from python2) in python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6

When I try to load a hickle file, this is the error, what to do?

```
hkl.load("sources_test.hkl")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hickle/hickle.py", line 515, in load raise RuntimeError("Cannot open file. This file was likely" RuntimeError: Cannot open file. This file was likely created with Python 2 and an old hickle version.
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the hickle file in Python 2.7, dump it with pickle using `protocol=0` (slow but safe) instead. Load the pickle file in Python 3.6, then dump it with hickle again so that you now have a hickle file compatible with Python 3.6.

Comment: pickle in 3.5 is giving this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Python3 expects a different encoding. You have to load the pickle with the parameter `encoding='latin1'`.